# Failed to open file, Error 2 - MySQL Import

Tags: mysql, linux, centos7, mariadb-10.3

I'm trying to import a MySQL Database via command line (Terminal). The file's path seems to be correct, but I keep getting an error message that is most likely showing that, the path of the SQL file I'm importing is not correct. Below is the sample of the command line I'm using and the error I'm getting...

NOTE: Linux Server, Centos 7 - MariaDB

```
source C:/Users/localcomputerUser/SQLFileFolder/SQLFile.sql
```

source C:/Users/localcomputerUser/SQLFileFolder/SQLFile.sql

Failed to open file 'C:/Users/localcomputerUser/SQLFileFolder/SQLFile.sql
', error: 2

Thanks for your support.

Comment: What makes the _file's path seem_ _to be correct_ to you?

Comment: @Armali if you have a suggestion, just go ahead and post it...

Comment: Yes, I suggest you answer questions in order to find out what's wrong.

Comment: If you are using any Linux based system, it's pretty obvious that `C:/` does not yield anything, as this is a Windows path

Comment: @NicoHaase The server is a Linux server, but the mySQL file is on a local Windows computer.